# How to log the installation date to the registry

Tags: wix, wix3

When an install completes successfully, the date and time and some other info needs to be written to the registry. How can a date be generated and how do you know if an install was completed successfully? (writing to the registry with wix is not a problem).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What about using standard [MSI properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367437(VS.85).aspx) [Date](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368261(VS.85).aspx) and [Time](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372079(VS.85).aspx)?

**Note:** Be warned that *despite* the documentation indicating the date will always be in the `MM/DD/YYYY` format, this is not in fact the case. A verbose MSI log on my system (in Australia) shows the property in `DD/MM/YYYY` format... e.g.:

```
Property(S): Date = 21/04/2010
```

Comment: Example usage : <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="InstalledOn" Value="[Date]"/>

Comment: From the MSDN doc Yan referenced it indicates "The format of the value depends upon the user's locale, and is the format obtained using GetDateFormat with the DATE_SHORTDATE option. The value of this property is set by the Windows Installer and not the package author.".

Answer (score 8):

For both date and time here is some sample code.

```xml
<RegistryValue Id="InstallDateTime"
               KeyPath="yes"
               Name="InstallDateTime"
               Value='[Date] [Time]'
               Type="string" />
```

[image]

If you want to use separator you can simply add it as text like:

```xml
<RegistryValue Id="InstallDateTime"
               KeyPath="yes"
               Name="InstallDateTime"
               Value='[Date]-[Time]'
               Type="string" />
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### Env variables??

---

Can you access environment variables like **PATH** etc. ??

> - These return the current system date and time...
>
>   You might want to access **%DATE%** & **%TIME%**

Alternately, since You are able to access the Registry, You can access the Env vars in the registry itself:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment\<variable>

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment\<variable>
```

GoodLUCK!!

Comment: Interesting - but I cannot find a WIX method to read a env var - the Environment element can "create|set|remove" only. Looking at the registry entries on my machine does not show date or time entries.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11181847/windows-environmental-variable-for-month-year