# Windows Environmental Variable for Month Year

Tags: windows, batch-file, environment-variables, shortcut

I have a process that writes log files and screenshots to a folder on a regular basis creating
between
30-50 files a week. The folder structure is `..\Year\Month\filename.ext`, and it cannot be changed.

I'd like to create a shortcut to stick in my Favorites so I can get to this folder quickly but I need a variable for the `YEAR` and `MONTH`. Are there an environmental variables for this?

Any bright ideas on how I could create one that updates automatically preferably without a script or scheduled job?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/864718/how-to-append-a-date-in-batch-files for some ideas.

Answer (score 8):

The `%DATE%` environment variable holds the current date. You might be tempted to parse the date with `%DATE:~6,4%` to get the year.

But this method would not be very solid. `%DATE%` returns the current date using the windows settings for the *"short date format"*. The problem is that the short date format setting is fully and endlessly customizable. One user can configure its system to show the short date as `29/06/2012`; while another user (even in the same system) may choose `Fri062912`. It's a complete nightmare for a BAT programmer.

One possible solution is to use **WMIC**, instead. WMIC is the WMI command line interface to WMI. WMI Windows Management Instrumentation is the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Management_Instrumentation

```
WMIC Path Win32_LocalTime Get Day,Hour,Minute,Month,Second,Year /Format:table
```

returns the date in a convenient way to directly parse it with a FOR.

Completing the parse and putting the pieces together

```
FOR /F "skip=1 tokens=1-6" %%A IN ('WMIC Path Win32_LocalTime Get Day^,Hour^,Minute^,Month^,Second^,Year /Format:table') DO (
  SET /A MONTH=%%D
  SET /A YEAR=%%F
)
```

your shortcut can point to a BAT file that includes the above code and then opens explorer on the right folder.

```
start "" "D:\FOLDER\%YEAR%\%MONTH%"
```