# Append ddmmyy and update Date Modified

Tags: batch-file

I would like to append the ddmmyy to the file name, copy the file and move to a specific location. So far this is what I have, and I am not able to get the Date Modified to work correctly.

original code:

```
@Echo Off
@For /F "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=/ " %%A in ('Date /t') do @( 
Set Day=%%A
Set Month=%%B
Set Year=%%C
Set Year=%%D
Set All=%%A%%B%%C%%D
)
@For %%a in ("*.txt") do copy %%a "import\%%~na_%All%.csv"
```

I tried the following:

```
@For %%a in ("*.txt") do copy %%a,,+ "import\%%~na_%All%.csv"

@For %%a in ("*.txt") do copy %%a "import\%%~na_%All%.csv,,+"

@For %%a in ("*.txt") do copy %%a "import\%%~na_%All%.csv",,+
```

The file name copies and appends the date correctly but, I can't get it to update the Date Modified correctly.

Answer (score 0):

copying a file does not modify the "last modified" date. You need to *touch* the file. Read this SO Question *https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51435/windows-version-of-the-unix-touch-command* and try

```
copy %%a +,,
copy %%a "import\%%~na_%All%.csv"
```

Apart of that, I can give you a couple of suggestions for improvement..

- you could just use the `%DATE%` environment variable instead of copying/parsing the output of `DATE` command.

  *if the format of `%DATE%` does not fit your requirements, take a look at this SO answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/11183896/30447.*
- you could use `MOVE` instead of `COPY` if you want to move the file (as you state in your Question).

  ```
  @echo off
  for %%a in (*.txt) do (
    copy "%%a" +,,
    move "%%a" "import\%%~na_%DATE%.csv"
  )
  ```